# Unable to make Axios call within AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda

I have the following function

```
const axios = require('axios')
const MY_API = process.env.myAPI

const getUserInfo = async (Id) => {
    console.log('Inside getUserInfo()')
    try {
        console.log('----Here I am ----')
        const response = await axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: `${MY_API}/customer/${Id}`,
            headers: await headers()
            })
        console.log(`----> ID: ${Id} \nName: ${response.data.name}`)
        return {
            name: response.data.name,
            city: response.data.city,
            zipCode: response.data.zipcode 
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Something went wrong with getUserInfo() call' )
        console.log(err.response.data)
        return err.response.data.Code
    }
}


exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const checkUserInfo = await getUserInfo(Id)
}
```

The output I get is as below

```
START RequestId: edeb9bf3-bcad-4de9-a549-23920f5de891 Version: $LATEST
2020-11-05T09:39:38.175Z    edeb9bf3-bcad-4de9-a549-23920f5de891    INFO    
Homer 
Springvale 
1234
2020-11-05T09:39:38.175Z    edeb9bf3-bcad-4de9-a549-23920f5de891    INFO    Inside getUserInfo()
2020-11-05T09:39:38.175Z    edeb9bf3-bcad-4de9-a549-23920f5de891    INFO    ----Here I am ----
END RequestId: edeb9bf3-bcad-4de9-a549-23920f5de891
REPORT RequestId: edeb9bf3-bcad-4de9-a549-23920f5de891  Duration: 5.45 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 32 MB
```

I'm puzzled as to what am I missing here, it seems that API call is never made. I'm using nodejs 12.x

Comment: where's the header() coming from?

Comment: did you add execution time limit ?

Answer (score 0):

Default timeout is 3 seconds for a Lambda function.
Your code is executing (most likely timing out) and your function is exiting. Because the function exits before an axios timeout is thrown, you never see the timeout error.

Also show the `headers` implementation and why is it async?

Are you actually passing the ID to the API request?
Looking at your handler function you are not.

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // Where is Id defined??
    const checkUserInfo = await getUserInfo(Id)
}
```

Try passing in the ID and increasing the function timeout to 1.5 mins and see if the error is thrown, or see if it works.